# Alexa won´t recognize when the user requests a dynamic entity

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

I want to use dynamic entities in a certain slot of my Alexa Skill. The slot type already exists and has some static values. However I am only interested in the dynamic slot values the user provides. I update the Dynamic Entities in the LaunchRequestHandle.
This is how an interaction using the specifies Dynamic Entities should go:
User: open [Skill Name]
Alexa: Welcome, ...
[Some other questions and answers]
Alexa: What tv channel would you like to watch?
User: I want to watch [Dynamic Slot Value]
Alexa: [goes to FallbackIntent]

I attached a shortened version of the code.

```
`const LaunchRequestHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return Alexa.getRequestType(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'LaunchRequest'
        || Alexa.getIntentName(handlerInput.requestEnvelope) === 'AMAZON.StartOverIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {        
        let replaceEntities = {
            type: "Dialog.UpdateDynamicEntities",
            updateBehavior: "REPLACE",
            types: [
                {
                  name: "canalEntretenimiento",
                  values: [
                    {
                      id: "1a",
                      name: {
                        value: "Antena 3",
                        synonyms: ["la tres"]
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      id: "1b",
                      name: {
                        value: "La Sexta",
                        synonyms: ["La seis"]
                      }
                    },
                  ]
                }
                ]
            };
        console.log(replaceEntities);
        
        const speakOutput = `Bienvenido, te gustaría ver la televisión o una película`;

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speakOutput)
            .reprompt(speakOutput)
            .addDirective(replaceEntities)
            .getResponse();
    }
};

[The user will have to go through other intents in order to get to the question that expects the Dynamic Slot in return]

const canalIntentHandler = {  
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'  
          && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'canalIntent';  
      },  
    async handle(handlerInput) {  
        const responseBuilder = handlerInput.responseBuilder;  
        const canalEntretenimiento = getStaticAndDynamicSlotValuesFromSlot(handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.slots.canalEntretenimiento);        
        speechText = ` No hemos encontrado el canal`;   
        
        if (canalEntretenimiento.dynamic.statusCode === 'ER_SUCCESS_MATCH') {
            speechText = `Reproduciendo`  + ` ${canalEntretenimiento.value}`; 
            }        
     
        return responseBuilder  
          .speak(speechText)
          .withShouldEndSession(false)
          .getResponse();  
      },  
    };  

//Aux functions
function getStaticAndDynamicSlotValues (slots) {
    const slotValues = {}
    for (let slot in slots) {
        slotValues[slot] = getStaticAndDynamicSlotValuesFromSlot(slots[slot]);
    }
    return slotValues;
    };

function getStaticAndDynamicSlotValuesFromSlot (slot) {

    const result = {
        name: slot.name,
        value: slot.value,
        id:slot.id
    };
    console.log(result)

    if (((slot.resolutions || {}).resolutionsPerAuthority || [])[0] || {}) {
        slot.resolutions.resolutionsPerAuthority.forEach((authority) => {
            const slotValue = {
                authority: authority.authority,
                statusCode: authority.status.code,
                synonym: slot.value || undefined,
                resolvedValues: slot.value
            };
            if (authority.values && authority.values.length > 0) {
                slotValue.resolvedValues = [];

                authority.values.forEach((value) => {
                    slotValue.resolvedValues.push(value);
                });

            }

            if (authority.authority.includes('amzn1.er-authority.echo-sdk.dynamic')) {
                result.dynamic = slotValue;
            } else {
                result.static = slotValue;
            }
        });
    }
    return result;
};`
```

As I said, it seems as if Alexa doesn´t recognize the slot value (and/or the intent, the content of the user response may only be the slot value) and goes directly to FallbackIntent.

Answer (score 3):

I understand your FallbackIntent handler is triggered when using an utterance with a dynamic slot value. The FallbackIntent is triggered when a customer says something that doesn’t map to any intents in your skill. Therefore, I would recommend making sure you have sufficient sample utterances in your skill's interaction model for canalIntent. 20-30 sample utterances with a range of expected ways users will try to trigger this intent is usually sufficient. You have mentioned users may use just the slot name, so please also be sure to include a sample utterance of just "{canalEntretenimiento}".